# HLS works on everything but iOS devices

Tags: video, http-live-streaming, rtsp

Our custom streaming software takes RTSP from CCTV cameras and restreams it to HLS.

This has worked for years on all devices.

Now, it won't work on iOS> It's just a black screen. An ALL iso devices regardless of version.

Still works on PC, Mac, Android...

Our hls stream is video only. There is no audio.

The problem is not with the player because I tested other players and they do the same thing on iOS. Black screen or at best they freeze on the first picture and don't ever move.

Any advice on what the problem may be?

Comment: Probably a colorspace issue, but without knowing anything about your stream, it's impossible to help you.  Sorry.

Comment: Thank you. That helps. At least it gives me a direction to go...

Comment: We use ffmpeg to create an hls stream.

Comment: Show your full FFmpeg command and its output.